# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

For each linear operator $T$ on  $V$, find the eigenvalues of $T$ and an ordered basis $\beta$ for $V$ such that $[T]_\beta$ is a diagonal matrix. 
Where $V = M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$ and $T \left(\begin{matrix}a & b  \\c & d  \\\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}d & b\\ c & a\\ \end{matrix}\right)$ . 
I just get two eigenvalues both equal to one, the book says there are four eigenvalues, $1$ with multiplicity $3$ and $-1$ with multiplicity $1$. I cannot for the life of me figure out how they got it, please be as detailed as possible.

Comment: Try rewriting $\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d\end{array}\right)$ as a vector and see what $T$ does that to the vector. It makes it a bit clearer as to exactly why there is a negative eigenvalue and why there are actually four of them, not two. The matrix representation is a bit confusing in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first write down the obvious basis for $V$
$$
e_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
e_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
e_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
e_4 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix},
$$
and then the matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis
$$
T = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
by setting $(a,b,c,d)$ equal to $(1,0,0,0)$, $(0,1,0,0)$, $(0,0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,0,1)$ in the given equation for $T$.

Doing cofactor expansion, we see that $\det(T) = -1$. Since the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, we must have at least one negative eigenvalue! (This is what @Cameron Williams was referring to.)

Since the middle two columns of the matrix of $T$ agree with the identity matrix, we see that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \qquad\mbox{and}\qquad \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

If we try multiplying $T$ by $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T$, the result is the other vector; by adding, we get 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Knowing that we have a negative eigenvalue to find, the next reasonable suspect works:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} = - \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
gives us our last eigenvalue of $-1$.

The ordered basis of $V$ we want is then $(e_2, e_3, e_1+e_4, e_1-e_4)$ (or any permutation of it).